# Laravel eloquent - filter by concatenation of multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, filtering

I'm new to Laravel, and I got stuck trying to perform the following. I have a simple users table with the following columns:

- `id`
- `first_name`
- `last_name`

I'm about to make a user list with an option of filtering. One of the filters is `full_name`, but I do not store `full_name` of the users, and I can't modify the table structure.

Over a few days I got to this:

```
$query = \DB::table('users');
$query->select(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `last_name`, `first_name`) 
        as `full_name`, id'))->having('full_name', 'LIKE',$input['filter_name']);
$result = $query->get(['*']);
```

But it's not working.

**Spec**: I'm using the latest laravel.

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you get an error? Read through this on debugging queries in laravel: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The first problem was, I forgot the "%" wildcard.

The second that is used a concatenated value as filter, then the Laravels paginate tried to count the overall result count, by using that concatenated value. Sure it does not exists. The solution is:

```
$query = \App\User::whereDeletedAt(null);
$query->where(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `last_name`, `first_name`)'), 'like', '%' . $input['filter_name'] . '%');
$query->paginate(15, ['*'], 'page', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the wildcards in the LIKE statement.

Instead of this

```
$query->select(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `last_name`, `first_name`) 
    as `full_name`, id'))->having('full_name', 'LIKE',$input['filter_name']);
```

Try:

```
$query->select(\DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", `last_name`, `first_name`) 
    as `full_name`, id'))->having('full_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['filter_name'] . '%');
```

Comment: If I using it with paginate `$query->paginate(10, ['*'], 'page', 1)`, I got the following error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `deleted_at` is null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null having `full_name` LIKE ad%".

It tries to count the overall result... Any solution for this?

Comment: @Olaszka i think the error is clear. It doesn't know what `full_name` is. I think you forgot something like `... as full_name`. Else update the question with the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of trying to achieve it by modyfing query, get query like as normal:

`$users = DB::table('users')->get();`
And then, use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-filter).
`->filter(function($key, $value) { return strpos($value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name'], $to_find) !== false })->all();`